# Convert javax.swing to command input

Tags: java, swing

How can I convert the `javax.swing.*` into normal command line prompt? I tried to test the code on https://compilr.com/ but since it has `javax.swing.*` it doesn't prompt a dialog.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Program
{
  public static void main ( String[] args)
  {
    int numOfGrades = 0, gradeCount = 0, sum = 0;
    char grade;
    String openMsg, getNumOfGrades, getGrades, outMsg1, gradeOut;

    openMsg = "Welcome.\n\n" +
    "Grading Scale: A = 4, B = 3, C = 2, D = 1, F = 0\n\n" +
    "Please tell me how many grades to enter today:";
    getNumOfGrades = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ( openMsg );
    numOfGrades = Integer.parseInt ( getNumOfGrades );



    while ( gradeCount != numOfGrades )
    {
      getGrades =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter grade number: "+ (gradeCount+1) + "\n" +
      "Grading Scale: A = 4, B = 3, C = 2, D = 1, F = 0\n\n");
      grade = getGrades.charAt ( 0 );
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ( null, grade );

      //int sum = 0;

      switch(grade)
      {
      case 'a': case 'A':
        grade = 4;
        break;
      case 'b': case 'B':
        grade = 3;
        break;
      case 'c': case 'C':
        grade = 2;
        break;
      case 'd': case 'D':
        grade = 1;
        break;
      case 'f': case 'F':
        grade = 0;
        break;
      default:
        String errOut = "Sorry, Invalid entry. Exiting Program!";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ( null, errOut );
        break;
      }

      sum += grade;

      gradeCount++;
    }

    double gpa = sum / gradeCount;

    outMsg1 = "You entered " + numOfGrades + " grades\n" +
    "Your GPA is: " + gpa + "\n" +
    "These were the grades you entered: "; //+ grade;  

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ( null, outMsg1 );

    System.exit ( 0 );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what you're trying to do. If you just want a runnable program then the easiest thing to do is to use command line arguments to pass your input rather than prompting for it.

Each command line argument after the name of the class to run is passed in as that args string array your main method receives. So you can simply read them out of this array.

If you want to prompt for input, then you want to write out the messages using `System.out.println`. The input can be read from "standard in" using `System.in`. Since this is an input stream it's usually wrapped in a BufferedReader and input stream reader. E.g.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("Type some data");
String theData = reader.readLine()
```